# When is it necessary to consider size consistency?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

For what kinds of reactions is it essential to account for [size consistency](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/size-consistency-in-computational-chemisty-methods)? To my understanding for dissociation reactions $(\ce{AB -> A + B})$ it is important to consider. However, is it also necessary to consider for isodesmic reactions? How about for other addition or insertion reactions?

Comment: Your terminology is, to some extent, rather obscure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isodesmic_reaction Dunno what "integration" is supposed to mean, insertion maybe?

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I meant insertion reaction.

Comment: @Mithoron Isodesmic is a fairly often-used term in my reading of the computational literature.  Isodesmic reactions are commonly used as exemplars of systems where the electronic character of the products and reactants are similar, allowing benchmarking/comparison of methods while introducing the minimum of effects from variations in gross electronic structure.

Comment: @hBy2Py Well, more importantly what is "size consistency" supposed to mean here? Lack of significant difference in size between atoms?

Comment: @Mithoron It's a specific term of art for a particular kind of error inherent to certain kinds of calculations. See [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/size-consistency-in-computational-chemisty-methods).

Comment: The obvious answer is that you should always worry about size consistency, however, the only method that truly suffers from it is truncated configuration interaction.